# ADMM on non-convex problem

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Suppose the minimization problem is

$$\operatorname{arg min} \limits_x f(x) + g(x)$$

where function $f$ is not convex but $g$ is. If we solve it using ADMM

$$\operatorname{arg min} \limits_{x_1,x_2}f(x_1) + g(x_2), s.t. x_1=x_2$$

the $x_2$ subproblem is solved in the standard way and $x_1$ subproblem is solved in a heuristic way such that the new $f(x_1)$ + penalty term is always smaller than the $f(x_1)$ + penalty term from the previous iteration.

Would it produce at least a sub-optimal result that is close to the optimal result?

Has anyone done this kind of analysis? If yes can someone point me to the link so I can read up?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "at least a sub-optimal result"? I guess that you may approach a local minimizer far from the glpobal one...

Comment: Without more information bout $f$ and $g$ there is absolutely nothing you can say. The local optimum could be arbitrarily far away from the global in both distance and value. And that's assuming it converges, which is by no means guaranteed, either.

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying. I can imagine it converge to a local minimum and it may or may not be close to the global minimum depends on the function itself and the parameter setting. However, why isn't convergence guaranteed if the heuristic method can always produce a $x_1^*$ that makes $f(x_1) +$ penalty term smaller after each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x_1)+g(x_2)$ will converge to a local optima, as per http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8033.
Note that $x_1$ and $x_2$ themselves might not converge (cf. Section 3.2.1 of Boyd et al., "Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers").

Answer (score 3):

A recent result at ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam15-62.pdf analyzed ADMM with nonconvex and nonsmooth functions. It establishes a set of conditions that the point sequence converges to a stationary point of the augmented Lagrangian. To your problem, the conditions allow $f(x_1)$ to be the sum of a Lipschitz continuous function and a nonconvex nonsmooth function (such as the $\ell_{1/2}$ quasi-norm and a piece-wise linear function) and $g(x_2)$ to be a Lipschitz continuous function. None of these functions needs to be convex.